# How does operating system distinguish between file and directory

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I was going through basics of File System implementation. While implementing for looking up for a file, how does the OS distinguish a file and the directory which it is in?

For example: If I want to lookup a file foo.c with the given path: /home/mac/work/foo.c, How does the OS decide home,mac and work are directories and foo.c is the file inside work directory

Comment: What OS? What file system? There are significant differences between them, even on Mac. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#OS_X) for an idea how much.

Comment: See also [HFS Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System#Design) and [HFS Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) for info on OS X file systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume this question pertains to Linux operating systems.

A file by definition is at leaf-level of a tree.  Therefore, anything that is suffixed with a `/` cannot be a file.

The leaf is another story.  `foo.c` might be a file or it might be a directory.  The OS has to look at it in order to determine which it is.  Internally, a directory is technically a file, but it behaves differently.

To complicate things, Linux has soft- and hard-links, which are special files that can link to a file or directory.  And indeed a directory might be the mount point for an entire file system.  It's quite common to mount a separate partition or drive as `/home`.  You don't really have to worry about these.  You are mostly concerned with the addressing.

If you want to find out what a file is in Linux, use `/usr/bin/stat`.